# Topology on set of smooth functions $\mathbb{R} \supset I \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, differential-topology

Let $I$ be a (connected) interval of the real line. I am interested in the set $X$ of all smooth functions $I \to \mathbb{R}$.

Does $X$ have a natural choice of topology?

Comment: There are a few topologies that could be considered "natural". Do you have any further information about what you plan to use this topology for? Also, is $I$ closed and/or bounded?

Comment: @TheoBendit I am trying to describe a specific class of Euclidean submanifolds. It turns out that any submanifold in this class is locally determined by a tuple of smooth functions $I \to \mathbb{R}$. However, some tuples lead to pathological cases (i.e., submanifolds that have singularities). I wish to get some understanding of the subset of $X$ which is set-isomorphic to my set of (singularity-free) submanifolds.

Comment: @TheoBendit To answer your second question, $I$ could be assumed to be bounded. If it helps, even closed.

Comment: Uniform convergence of all derivatives on all compact subsets. This makes the space a nuclear Frechet space.

Comment: @Jochen Could you please elaborate on why such a choice would be the most natural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topology of uniform convergence of all derivatives on $X=C^\infty(I)$ is given by the sequence of seminorms $\|f\|_n=\sup\{|f^{(k)}(x)|: x\in I_n, 0\le k\le n\}$ where $I_n$ is an increasing sequence of compact intervalls with union $I$. Some reasons why this should be the most *natural choice*: It makes the algebraic operations on $C^\infty(I)$ (sums, products, derivatives) continuous, it is metrizable so that you can check continuity and other topological questions with sequences. For all analytical questions it is crucial that the space is complete. Moreover, $C^\infty(I)$ is a *Montel* space, i.e., the bounded sets are relatively compact which can be very helpful for existence proofs (it is even better than just Montel, a so-called *Schwartz* space). Finally, it is a nuclear Frechet space which very convenient e.g. when you deal with vector valued smooth functions.

Comment: You want the $I_n$ to be compact, yes?

Comment: Thanks, zhw. Corrected.